# Multiple LEFT JOINS with Multiple COUNT() count all colum

Tags: php, mysql, join, count, left-join

I have 4 tables.

table groups

```
| ID | NAME |
  1    Premium
  2    Silver
```

table user

```
| ID | group_id | NAME |
  1       1      Serhan
  2       2      Farhat
```

table user_statistics

```
| ID | user_id | TYPE |
  1       1      1
  2       2      0
```

table votes

```
| ID | user_id | VOTE |
  1       1      1
  2       2      0
  3       1      0
```

I created an sql query to retrieve user details who is in same group. It's worked! Then I want to retrieve any of vote that have been voted to user in groups. I want to count the vote. So basically I've made this sql query.

```
global $conn;
$res_groups = array();
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM groups
");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while ($group = $stmt->fetch()){
    $groups = array();
    $groups['id'] = $group['id'];
    $groups['name'] = $group['name'];

    $user_arr = array();
    $stmts = $conn->prepare('
        SELECT l.*,
        (SELECT MAX(ls.date) from user_statistics ls WHERE ls.user_id = l.id GROUP BY ls.user_id) as ls_date,
        (SELECT SUM(IF(ls.type="0", ls.type, 0)) FROM user_statistics ls WHERE ls.user_id = l.id GROUP BY ls.user_id) as ls_us,
        (SELECT SUM(IF(ls.type="1", ls.type, 0)) FROM user_statistics ls WHERE ls.user_id = l.id  GROUP BY ls.user_id) as ls_uk,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_statistics WHERE type="1" AND ls.user_id = l.id GROUP BY ls.user_id) as totals,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes v WHERE v.vote=0 AND confirm=0 AND v.user_id = l.id) as badvote,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes v WHERE v.vote=1 AND confirm=0 AND v.user_id = l.id) as goodvote
        FROM user l
        LEFT JOIN
        user_statistics ls on l.id = ls.user_id
        LEFT JOIN votes v on v.user_id = l.id
        WHERE l.group_id = '.$groups['id'].' AND status = 1
        GROUP BY l.id,ls.user_id
    ');
    $stmts->execute();
    $stmts->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    while ($usr = $stmts->fetch()){

        $totalvote=($usr['badvote']+$usr['goodvote']);
        if($totalvote>0){
            $badvote=bcdiv($usr['badvote']*100/$totalvote,1,2);
            $goodvote=bcdiv($usr['goodvote']*100/$totalvote,1,2);
        }else{
            $badvote=0;
            $goodvote=0;
        }
        $votes[] = array(
            "count" => $usr['badvote'],
            "percent" => $badvote
        );
        $votes[] = array(
            "count" => $usr['goodvote'],
            "percent" => $goodvote
        );

        $user_arr[] = array(
            "id" => $usr['id'],
            "group_id" => $usr['group_id'],
            "name" => $usr['name'],
            "votes_summary" => $votes
        );
    }
    $groups['list'] = $user_arr;
    $res_groups[] = $groups;
}
```

All code seems work unless one thing. The VOTE is always return to count all column in my database VOTES and apply the data to all of my user. What I want is to get how many vote that each user get based on vote type GOOD or BAD.

Any help will be nice.

Comment: Withhout data it will be difficult to help you see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: There you go, I edited first post, hope you can help me

Comment: You are missing a lot of fields. Please try to make a dbfiddle example and see if that works with your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking to your code you could refactor your query avoiding select subquery one for each row and using two subquery with group by in join.

You have also the same code  for bad and good vote could be  you need  different code for obtain different values

```
    SELECT l.*
      , t1.ls_date
      , t1.ls_us
      , t1.ls_uk
      , t2.totals
      , t2.badvote
      , t2.goodvote
    FROM user l
    INNER JOIN  (
     SELECT ls.user_id
        , MAX(ls.date) ls_date
        , SUM(IF(ls.type="0", ls.type, 0)) ls_us
        , SUM(IF(ls.type="1", ls.type, 0)) ls_uk
     from user_statistics ls 
     GROUP BY ls.user_id 
    )  t1 on t1.user_id = l.id
    LEFT JOIN ( 
        SELECT v.user_id
        , sum( case when type="1" then 1 else 0 end ) totals
        /* these are the same */
        , sum ( case when v.vote=1 AND confirm=0  then 1 else 0 END ) badvote  
        /* these are the same */
        , sum ( case when v.vote=1 AND confirm=0  then 1 else 0 END ) goodvote 
      FROM votes v
    ) t2 ON t2.user_id  = l.id 
    WHERE l.group_id = '.$groups['id'].' 
    AND status = 1
```

And you should avoid the use of PHP var in SQL (you are at risk for SQL injection). For this you should take a look at your db driver for prepared statement and binding value, or at least be sure you sanitize properly the php var content

Comment: This will output same as my code in first post, The user vote is the same for all user (it show in global not based on user votes. User 1 should have 1 good vote and 1 bad vote, user 2 have 1 bad vote and none good vote.

Comment: Anyway the same that you hint is, "CASE WHEN v.vote=0" and the others "CASE WHEN v.vote=1" (Miss type in first post) also you have to add END at the close bracket.

Comment: Anyway. Thanks for the code, it's help me figure out to fix.